# Is Ignite Web Console available for Apache Ignite 2.0

Tags: datagrid, ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain

I have upgraded Apache Ignite from 1.9 to 2.0. As per documentation of 2.0 all cache entries stored Off-Heap but When I Monitor the web console it showing all entries on the heap.So my question is Ignite Web Console working properly with Apache Ignite 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm one of the Web Console developers.
We are looking into this.
We'll try to fix this in nearest ignite-2.1 release.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since version 2.0 with default configuration Ignite stores entries in off-heap. It's a problem with metrics.

Web-console working properly with Ignite 2.0, but it seems that it uses broken metric for off-heap entries count.

Comment: I think that off-heap metrics are showing as on-heap.